# Calculating joint cumulative distribution function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

given the joint probability density function

$f_{XY}(x;y)=
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if (x; y) $\in[0; 1]\times[0; 1]$} \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$

I want to calculate the joint cumulative distribution function $F_{XY}$, using

$F_{XY}(x; y)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{y} f_{XY}(\alpha;\beta)d\alpha d\beta$.

How should I set that integral ? More precisely, I have to write something like

$F_{XY}(x;y)=
\begin{cases}
\int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{y} 0·d\alpha d\beta,
& \text{if x, y $\in]-\infty; 0[$} \\
\int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{y} 1·d\alpha d\beta, 
& \text{if (x; y) $\in[0; 1]\times[0; 1]$} \\
\int_{-\infty}^{x} \int_{-\infty}^{y} 0·d\alpha d\beta,
& \text{if x, y $\in]1; +\infty[$}
\end{cases}$

but I'm not sure that what I wrote is right.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Think geometrically. $F_{XY}(x,y)$ is the area of the part of the square southwest (below and to the left) of $(x,y)$.  So for instance if $0 \le x,y \le 1$, then $F_{XY}(x,y)=xy$.

Comment: Hi! But $F_{XY}$ should not be a volume? However, following your hint, I have $F_{XY}(x;y)=
\begin{cases}
xy, & \text{if (x; y) $\in[0; 1]\times[0; 1]$} \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$. Is it correct ?

Comment: It can be interpreted as volume since the height of the pdf is uniformly $1$ above the unit square.

Comment: Yes, but the $F_{XY}$ I wrote, is it correct ? I know that it must be $F_{XY}(+\infty; +\infty)=1$ and $F_{XY}$ it must be a nondecreasing function, while my $F_{XY}(x; y)=0$ if $x,y\in]1;+\infty[$.

Comment: Your $F_{XY}$ is not correct.  For instance, if both $x,y$ are in $[0,1]$, your result is infinite (integral diverges); if your $x,y$ are both greater than $1$, your proposed cdf gives a value of $0$, but it should be $1$.  Also you have left out some cases, such as when one of $x,y$ is greater than $1$ and the other is between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Ok, you are really patient!!! Thanks so much :)